# How do I find folders without a certain name?

Tags: command-line, find

I'm trying to find a lot of folders, all without a certain bracket.
They're movie folders, like so:

```
Zombie Flesh Eaters (1979) [tmdb-7219]
Zombieland (2009) [tmdb-19908]
Zombieland Double Tap (2019) [tmdb-338967]
```

But I need to find the ones WITHOUT the [tmdb] bracket.

I'm not sure how to do this?

**Quick edit:**
Tried using the reg-ex `\[.*?\]` to find everything with a bracket in it, but I'm not sure if that works properly (I'm not that good at regex, but using a reg-ex tester confirms it looks for anything inside brackets).

But I need to find the folders WITHOUT the brackets.. And I don't know how to do this

Comment: How are you finding in the first place? In some cases, a `grep -v` may help you out.

Comment: Using this string `'\[.*?\]'` when using `find`.. Not even sure that works properly. But I need to find the folders without the bracket :)

Comment: We need this information to be in the question. Use "edit" to clarify your questions. Comments may not be read or may disappear anytime.

Comment: Does your "reg-ex tester" use the same regex flavour as `find`? `.*?` looks like Perl, it doesn't make sense to have `?` after `*` in BRE or ERE.

Comment: Just tried this one:
https://www.regextester.com/

With the result:
https://i.imgur.com/mKIBLJC.png -- again sorry; I don't know much about regex :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done easily.

```bsh
ls -Aq1 | grep -Pv '.*\[tmdb-\d+\].*'
```

Piping after `ls` is considered a bad thing in general however, I assume all the folders aren't weirdly named because they're just movie folders, so I think piping after `ls` is fine here.

I haven't tested it but I'm pretty confident that it should work.

Also, I'm guessing that you'll be putting those folders in a loop to add the id to the name. Pure guess but I assume. Then this is handy because the ls output (because of the `-..1`) will be in a list. So you can easily do this to process the folders one by one:

```bsh
ls -Aq1 | grep -Pv '.*\[tmdb-\d+\].*' | \
while read -r level
do
   ...
done
```

or

```bsh
ls -Aq1 | \
while read -r level
do
   if ! echo "$level" | grep -Pq '.*\[tmdb-\d+\].*'
   then
      ...
   fi
done
```

Comment: This also worked very well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`find` features the `-not` operator. Tell it where to search, what kind of item to find (e.g. `-type d` to find only folders) and what should not be in the name, i.e `-not -name '*\[*\]'`. Thus

```
find /somewhere -type d -not -name '*\[*\]'
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked very well for me. Just added a `-maxdepth 1` in my case :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to search recursively, then the bash shell's `extglob` can do negation using `!(pattern)` ex.

```
shopt -s extglob

printf '%s\n' !(*\[tmdb-*\]*)/
```

The `extglob` option is probably enabled by default in your interactive bash shell. The trailing `/` is only necessary if you need to exclude plain files from the match - equivalent to the `find` command's `type -d`.

Ex. given a directory with contents

```
$ ls
'Zombie Flesh Eaters (1979) [something else here]'  'Zombieland (2009) [tmdb-19908]'
'Zombie Flesh Eaters (1979) [tmdb-7219]'            'Zombieland Double Tap (2019) [tmdb-338967]'
'Zombieland (2009)'
```

then

```
$ printf '%s\n' !(*\[tmdb-*\]*)/
Zombie Flesh Eaters (1979) [something else here]/
Zombieland (2009)/
```

or

```
$ ls -d !(*\[tmdb-*\]*)/
'Zombie Flesh Eaters (1979) [something else here]/'  'Zombieland (2009)/'
```

Unlike `find`, this won't match hidden directories by default (although you can include them by setting `shopt -s dotglob`).

If you *do* need to search recursively, you can add `shopt -s globstar` and use `**/!(*\[tmdb-*\]*)/` although I'd likely choose `find` in this case.